# PayPal Smart Buttons Error: "Expected order id to be passed"

Tags: javascript, paypal-rest-sdk

i have a problem : I'm trying to figure out what it is since last friday, I can't find any good docs and no clues on the internet, I share some screenshots if anyone could help it would be awesome, by the way my problem is that when clicking on the paypal smart buttons that I integrated, i get in the console "expected an order id to be passed" unfortunately I can't find what is that order id thing

```js
    paypal.Buttons({

        style: {
            shape: 'rect',
            color: 'gold',
            layout: 'vertical',
            label: 'pay',

        },

        // Sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked
        createOrder: function (data, actions) {
            var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();
            // Call your backend to create the Checkout Session
            $.ajax({
                data: {
                    id: cookie
                },
                type: "POST",
                url: "create.php",
                success: function (response) {
                    response = JSON.parse(response)
                    surname = []
                    surname = response.name.split(/(\s+)/).filter(e => e.trim().length > 0)

                    const Cart5 = [];

                    function Cart(description, name, unit_amount, quantity) {
                        this.description = description;
                        this.name = name;
                        this.unit_amount = {
                            value: unit_amount,
                            currency_code: 'EUR'
                        };
                        this.quantity = quantity;
                        this.category = 'PHYSICAL_GOODS';
                    }
                    cartArray.forEach(element => {
                        var item = new Cart(element.id, element.name, element.price, element.count);
                        Cart5.push(item);
                    })
                    JSON.stringify(Cart5);


                    orderid = makeid(12);
                    const paymentData = {
                        //authorization: 'AdhHUVsamn71V-Xs5JZVpzL4v6ElEKiYywV6PwF7rRwCwRQ-AZHMcLELmvQuWlS1pL19iiCbbZUIupTt',
                        intent: "CAPTURE",
                        env: "production",
                        application_context: {
                            brand_name: "Skunker",
                            locale: "fr-FR",
                            landing_page: "BILLING",
                            shipping_preference: "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS",
                        },
                        purchase_units: [{
                            reference_id: orderid,
                            custom_id: orderid,
                            description: 'Achat chez Skunker.Store',
                            invoice_id: orderid,
                            payer: {
                                email_address: response.email,
                            },
                            amount: {
                                currency_code: "EUR",
                                value: shoppingCart.totalCart() - (shoppingCart.totalCart() * sessionStorage.getItem('discount') / 100) + 6.15,
                                breakdown: {
                                    item_total: {
                                        currency_code: "EUR",
                                        value: shoppingCart.totalCart()
                                    },
                                    tax_total: {
                                        currency_code: "EUR",
                                        value: 0.20
                                    },
                                    shipping: {
                                        currency_code: "EUR",
                                        value: 5.95
                                    },
                                    handling: {
                                        currency_code: "EUR",
                                        value: 0.00
                                    },
                                    insurance: {
                                        currency_code: "EUR",
                                        value: 0.0
                                    },
                                    shipping_discount: {
                                        currency_code: "EUR",
                                        value: 0.00
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            items: Cart5,
                            shipping: {
                                method: "La Poste - Colissimo",
                                address: {
                                    name: {
                                        given_name: surname[0],
                                        surname: surname[1],
                                    },
                                    address_line_1: response.address,
                                    admin_area_2: response.city,
                                    postal_code: response.postalCode,
                                    country_code: "FR"
                                },
                                phone_number: {
                                    country_code: '33',
                                    national_number: response.tel,
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }

                    return actions.order.create(paymentData);
                }
            })

        },

        // Finalize the transaction after payer approval
        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function (orderData) {
                // Full available details
                console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));

                // Show a success message within this page, e.g.
                const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                element.innerHTML = '';
                element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
                $.ajax({
                    data: JSON.stringify(paymentData),
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "https://skunker.store/scripts/paid.php",
                    success: function (response) {}
                })

                // When ready to go live, remove the alert and show a success message within this page. For example:
                // var element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                // element.innerHTML = '';
                // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
            });
        },
        onError: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
    }).render('#payBtn');
```

And this is the error I get :

```
Error: Expected an order id to be passed
    at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.label=pay&style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&style.menuPlacement=below&components.0=buttons&locale.country=FR&locale.lang=fr&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVhTMWxLcXR2cjkzbDVkYlFPTE9nclJCYlNKMWt0cmNnYkpMZnJjRWEyckhING1ZYzVvWlQ1dmxpWUZDMnRobUFlcDVic1h4RmF1WEJ1cDMmY3VycmVuY3k9RVVSIiwiYXR0cnMiOnsiZGF0YS1zZGstaW50ZWdyYXRpb24tc291cmNlIjoiYnV0dG9uLWZhY3RvcnkiLCJkYXRhLXVpZCI6InVpZF9tdmh4dGh4aHhlYW13bHJzYXVna2dqeGRmcmpqenMifX0&clientID=AXS1lKqtvr93l5dbQOLOgrRBbSJ1ktrcgbJLfrcEa2rHH4mYc5oZT5vliYFC2thmAep5bsXxFauXBup3&sdkCorrelationID=f540177905bdc&storageID=uid_dbb0ba13c9_mtq6mzg6ndi&sessionID=uid_0e8f15ce50_mtq6ntq6nte&buttonSessionID=uid_1e5135ffcf_mtq6ntq6nte&env=sandbox&buttonSize=huge&fundingEligibility=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&platform=desktop&experiment.enableVenmo=false&experiment.disablePaylater=false&experiment.enableVenmoAppLabel=false&flow=purchase&currency=EUR&intent=capture&commit=true&vault=false&renderedButtons.0=paypal&renderedButtons.1=card&debug=false&applePaySupport=false&supportsPopups=true&supportedNativeBrowser=false&allowBillingPayments=true:1338:178001
```

I tried putting only the amount into the data and it still doesn't work, I also tried to add an order ID but it doesn't work
[image: Input]
[image: output]

Comment: Hey there, please avoid using images whenever you can. You can copy and paste code and outputs directly. The image quality is so low it can't be read. What does the docs say about the order id? Your question makes me think you don't understand what it is, but it's a mandatory field.

Comment: Hello,
I couldn't avoid using images but I can upload them somewhere else so you can see them if necessary, and about the docs I red them all but I don't figure out what is the problem, at first it worked without an order id thing, then I did dome edits and now I can't make it work, I tried using the code I did at first but even this one isn't working

Comment: To which line is the error message referring?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a mess, you're doing an ajax call to a "create.php" on your server, but for some reason not calling the PayPal API from there (with the Checkout-PHP-SDK or similar), but are instead using that response to then create an order from the client-side (which is what `actions.order.create` does)

This doesn't make any real sense. If you are using a server, you should have two routes: `create.php` and `capture.php?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"` (use a JSON `body` parameter to `fetch` rather than GET URL string, if desired) both of which communicate with the PayPal API themselves, to create and capture an order respectively. It does not make sense to combine your own server operations with JS SDK client-side methods.

So, you should switch over completely to this server pattern example: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , and in each of the respective routes that are called (create.php / capture.php or similar) you can either write your own HTTPS calls for the PayPal API, or use the [Checkout-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK) to abstract them as desired, and return the JSON response to the fetch caller.

---

I do not recommend trying to get what you have to work, but the main reason it is not working is a failure to return a JavaScript Promise properly. You are invoking an asynchronous $.ajax and not returning anything after doing so, hence the error "Expected an order id to be passed" since you actually returned nothing (even though you think you did); in reality you just spun off an asynchronous $.ajax to do its own thing and that function's result is never fed back (nor would it be if you returned its result, since it uses a callback rather than promises).

The simplest way to get a promise when calling your own server routes is to use `fetch` instead of `$.ajax`, then you can just return the result of the fetch. It is theoretically possible to turn a `$.ajax` callback into a promise and return that, but I would not spend any time on this if I were you; the built-in browser `fetch` creates a promise for you and is preferred in modern JS.

Comment: The create.php isn't related to the PayPal API, it is to gather some informations about the client making the purchase, this is the create.php :

`<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$date = date("Y-m-d");
include 'db.php';


$sql = "SELECT name, address, postalCode, city, tel, email FROM users WHERE id = '$id'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo json_encode($row);
        }`

And $id is the id of the client not the order id

Comment: I used
`<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=client_ID&currency=EUR" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
`
to communicate with PayPal API

Comment: Look, here is the payload : https://skunker.store/payload.png
And here is the answer preview : https://skunker.store/response_preview.png

It says that the link got created and it is, it's the 1 one, but when I click on the paypal button to pay the window opens and then closes itself before sending me the error 'Expected an order id to be passed'

Comment: I'm aware of all this about what you are doing, however it is very odd/not recommendable, and my answer stands. Since you are using a server for anything, the create and capture should be done via API from PHP -- which is doing other things, but should *also* be calling the PayPal API and providing a result that can be used by the JS SDK (without actions.order create, and without actions.order.capture).